# TYPO3: local ddev installation is working, deploy on server not -> white screen

Tags: typo3, typo3-11.x

I've got a local TYPO3 11.5.x ddev intallation which is working fine. I transferred the project via deployer and bitbucket pipeline to my server. There I have a symlink which is pointing to the current release and the domain is pointing in the public folder of the current release. Unfortunately I always get a white screen on firefox and a 500er error message on chrome.

I already activated error display and got this error display:
[image: Error Display]

I have really no clue what that could mean and would appreciate any help.

Thanks, Mylene

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message states that there is a problem with at least one folder.

You can go to the **install tool** / **admin tools**: `Environment` -> `Directory Status` and try to create all necessary folders.

If this does not work you may need to correct the rights by hand.
Have a look at the commands `chmod` and `chown` from your server.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer!
instal tool says as follows:
`/public/fileadmin is not a directory
Directory /public/fileadmin should be a directory, but is of type link`

fileadmin is a symlink to the shared folder because of deployer. The automatic fix doesn't work. On my server I have these rights: lrwxrwxrwx
Same for some other symlinks. Sorry, don't know what to do :(

Comment: Just realized that something went wrong with the symlinks. Somehow they were created in a wrong way and didn't work. Error is gone after fixing :)